# Facebook Graph API unique id

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get my Facebook id from an Android app. I logged in and I get the id, but the problem is that, I see that the id obtained from my app is different from that obtained via browser.

How do I get a unique id which, when sent to another phone, can be used to open a Facebook profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ID you get after login, it is a unique one but it is "App Scoped". It will only be unique in that App. The one you get in the browser is the "Global ID", you can´t get or use it in any App and you can´t match it with the App Scoped ID.

Check out the changelog for more information about App Scoped IDs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

Comment: Thanks a lot. but there is a way to get global id from login?